# MyBatis: How to map underscore result to camelcase for one specific statement only?

Tags: mybatis

I have a statement in the mybatis mapper.xml file:

```
 <select id="queryCorpAndDept" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
   SELECT ORGAN_NAME, ORGAN_ID FROM PUB_ORGAN
 </select>
```

The statement above will return a list of HashMap. The keys of the hashmap will be `ORGAN_NAME`, `ORGAN_ID`.  I know MyBatis has a setting named `mapUnderscoreToCamelCase` to map undercase to camelcase.

But is there another way to map underscore to camelcase without defining a JAVA Bean ?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: By using Column alias `SELECT organ_name "organName" ...`

Comment: It works in mysql, but in oracle,  it returns ORGANNAME.

Comment: It works for me. I use it all the time. Dont forget the the double quotes `"` around the column alias

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla OK, I'll have a try. Thanks.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla Yeah, It works exactly.

Comment: added it as the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use column aliases to be able to do selective `camelCasing` as shown below:

```
<select id="queryCorpAndDept" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" 
  resultType="java.util.HashMap">
    SELECT ORGAN_NAME "organName", ORGAN_ID "organId" FROM PUB_ORGAN
</select>
```